# ORA-01722: invalid number When I try to execute an store procedure. Oracle error

Tags: oracle

I know ORA-01722 occurs when I try to convert an invalid character to number. For example: "a123". In this case I only try to make a where condition, where the parameter is the ID of the table and the parameter is defined based on table type.

```
PROCEDURE SP_CPR_AGRUPAR_COMPRA(ID_SOLICITUD IN cpr_solicitud.id%type, ID_GRUPO IN cpr_solicitud.ID_GRUPO%type ) AS
BEGIN

 UPDATE cpr_solicitud
 SET ID_GRUPO=ID_GRUPO
 WHERE id=ID_SOLICITUD;

END SP_CPR_AGRUPAR_COMPRA;
```

I try to format the *ID_SOLICITUD* with TO_NUMBER function but the error continue. Something like this:

```
UPDATE cpr_solicitud
SET ID_GRUPO=ID_GRUPO
WHERE id=TO_NUMBER(ID_SOLICITUD);
```

I did a test passing directly the information and it works.

```
UPDATE cpr_solicitud SET ID_GRUPO = 18 WHERE id = 942000;
```

I did many test and the conclusion is that the error is related to the ID_SOLICITUD parameter. I don't why but if I pass the ID_GRUPO and I leave the ID_SOLICITUD it works.

It's works:

```
UPDATE cpr_solicitud
SET ID_GRUPO=ID_GRUPO
WHERE id=1
```

It's not works:

```
UPDATE cpr_solicitud
SET ID_GRUPO=1
WHERE id=TO_NUMBER(ID_SOLICITUD);
```

Comment: What is the datatype of cpr_solicitud.id? Also, `SET ID_GRUPO=ID_GRUPO` probably isn't doing what you want it to do.

Comment: Does your table also have a column called `ID_SOLICITUD`?

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica the datatype in the table is NUMBER(38,0). ID_GRUPO. It's foreign key with other table with the same datatype (NUMBER(38,0))

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes. But in this case ID_SOLICITUD is the ID in the table. It's only the parameter name (I know, It could be confusing)

Comment: No, not "it could be"; it *is* confusing, so Oracle has fixed rules to resolve the confusion. [You're seeing the documented behaviour.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-name-resolution.html#GUID-A551A39D-7DF8-4525-BE0F-1F46FE04ED09)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As stated in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-name-resolution.html#GUID-A551A39D-7DF8-4525-BE0F-1F46FE04ED09):

> If a SQL statement references a name that belongs to both a column and either a local variable or formal parameter, then the column name takes precedence.
>
> **Caution**: When a variable or parameter name is interpreted as a column name, data can be deleted, changed, or inserted unintentionally.

In your code,

```
SET ID_GRUPO=ID_GRUPO
```

clearly falls into that warning, as @Bob hinted. Every row that matched the filter would be updated with it's current value (i.e. nothing changes), not the value passed into the procedure. As you've confirmed in a comment that the table has a column called `ID_SOLICITUD` too, so does:

```
WHERE id=ID_SOLICITUD;
```

You are getting the error because it is implicitly converting the *column value* from `ID_SOLICITUD` - which is presumably not numeric - to a number so it can be compared with `id`. The `ID_SOLICITUD` parameter value is not being used, so its data type isn't relevant. You are effectively doing:

```
UPDATE cpr_solicitud
SET cpr_solicitud.ID_GRUPO=cpr_solicitud.ID_GRUPO
WHERE cpr_solicitud.id=cpr_solicitud.ID_SOLICITUD;
```

which clearly isn't what you intended. If you run that statement on its on you'll get the same error.

You can either prefix the variable names with the object they actually belong to:

```
PROCEDURE SP_CPR_AGRUPAR_COMPRA(ID_SOLICITUD IN cpr_solicitud.id%type, ID_GRUPO IN cpr_solicitud.ID_GRUPO%type ) AS
BEGIN

 UPDATE cpr_solicitud
 SET ID_GRUPO=SP_CPR_AGRUPAR_COMPRA.ID_GRUPO
 WHERE id=SP_CPR_AGRUPAR_COMPRA.ID_SOLICITUD;

END SP_CPR_AGRUPAR_COMPRA;
```

or (more simply and safely, perhaps) change the names, e.g. with a simple prefix:

```
PROCEDURE SP_CPR_AGRUPAR_COMPRA(p_ID_SOLICITUD IN cpr_solicitud.id%type, p_ID_GRUPO IN cpr_solicitud.ID_GRUPO%type ) AS
BEGIN

 UPDATE cpr_solicitud
 SET ID_GRUPO=p_ID_GRUPO
 WHERE id=p_ID_SOLICITUD;

END SP_CPR_AGRUPAR_COMPRA;
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex Poole. I really didn't know about this. Again, Thanks for your help